# Moment.js Format time for ZH_CN locale

Tags: javascript, localization, momentjs

I am trying to format a date with moment.js using the ZH_CN locale. I am using the following code:

```
moment('2013-12-31T13:21:55+00:00').locale('zh_cn').format("LL h:m:s:SSS")
```

This returns the following date: **2013年12月31日 1:21:55:000**

The time is not correctly formatted however. I was hoping the time would have the appropraite Chinese characters after each digit.I looked within moment-with-locales.js and noticed that the following is defined for the ZH_CN locale:

```
  relativeTime : {
        future : '%s内',
        past : '%s前',
        s : '几秒',
        m : '1分',
        mm : '%d分',
        h : '1小时',
        hh : '%d小时',
        d : '1天',
        dd : '%d天',
        M : '1个月',
        MM : '%d个月',
        y : '1年',
        yy : '%d年'
    }
```

These characters are not getting returned in the time even though I specify them in the format string (h:m:s:sss). Anything I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `relativeTime` customization only affects functions that produce relative time output, such as `fromNow`.

Additionally, only the localized format specifiers such as `LL` will contain the characters you're looking for.  You can combine them to get the desired output.

```
var m = moment('2013-12-31T13:21:55+00:00').locale('zh_cn');

m.format("LL")        // "2013年12月31日"
m.format("LLL")       // "2013年12月31日凌晨5点21分"
m.format("LT")        // "凌晨5点21分"
m.format("LTS")       // "凌晨5点21分55秒"
m.format("LL[]LTS")   // "2013年12月31日凌晨5点21分55秒"
```

I believe the last one will suit your needs.  Note the use of `[]` is necessary just so that `LL` and `LTS` are interpreted as separate codes without introducing additional characters.